# Where should one ask about the patenting status of a particular language/technology?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, legal

I'd like to know the patenting / commercial ownership status of a particular language. In which Stack Exchange site should I ask these questions?

For instance can one implement Matlab language in his own software and sell it? Or, can one implement a language very similar to / identical to Visual Basic and sell it as a commercial software?

Another example, is there a patent/copyright on Autocad drawing files, i.e can one implement its support in their software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now there is no good place to ask law-related questions like the one you are proposing.

Your best bet is to go directly to the vendor and ask their advice.

Comment: So how do you recommend I ask them? This way **Hello I'm someone gonna clone your software and sell it, OK?** good?

Comment: @Hossein, well, yeah.  But be a little more tactful.  I'm not sure though.